# Autodesk Forge - Clarification Items within properties

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am pulling the properties for Fusion 360 files. There are objects within the collection returned that I would like clarification on. The file I am pulling is a single body that is a rod (image below).

The properties call returns three items. The first object has the name "RodDesign v2" and has only one parameter ("Name") within the properties object. The second has the same name, but has data for mass, volume, etc. The third object is the "Body1" which is obviously the extruded body for the rod.

One of those "RodDesign v2" items is clearly the overall item. However, I am unsure as to what the other one is and was hoping for clarification. Is there a list of all items that would be included in a properties call for a file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a list of all items that would be included in a properties call for a file?

The properties that can be possibly pulled from a model are specific to the properties available from the model. The extracted properties available at `GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties` should match those available in the designer view - barring a few properties beyond the current capabilities of the derivative service so let us know if any property missing is important to your needs.

As different model formats vary from each other unfortunately there's no comprehensive list of all properties there are that can be extracted.

> I am unsure as to what the other one is and was hoping for clarification

What is the other one here that needs clarification?

Comment: There are three objects returned when the properties request is made. One is named Body1 and that one is obvious. Another is named RodDesign v2 and is the main component. The third is also called RodDesign v2 but has only one property - the name. It is this third one that I am not sure what it is.